# Diff-in-diff using Instrumental Variables: How to implement with ivreg? (interaction between endogenous and exogenous variables)

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'd like to estimate the effect of a treatment on two separate groups, so something of the form

[Equation 1](https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?Y_i%20%3D%20%5Cbeta_0%20+%20%5Cbeta_1%20M_i%20+%20%5Cbeta_2%20T_i%20+%20%5Cbeta_3%20M_i%5Ctimes%20T_i%20+%20u_i%2C)

T being the treatment and M the dummy separating the two groups.

The problem is that the treatment is correlated to other variables that affect Y. Luckily, there exists a variable Z that serves as an instrument for T. What I've been able to implement in R was to "manually" run 2SLS, following the stages

[Equation 2](https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Cwidehat%7BT%7D_i%20%3D%20%5Cwidehat%5Calpha_0%20+%20%5Cwidehat%5Calpha_1%20Z_i)

and

[Equation 3](https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?Y_i%20%3D%20%5Cbeta_0%20+%20%5Cbeta_1%20M_i%20+%20%5Cbeta_2%20%5Cwidehat%7BT%7D_i%20+%20%5Cbeta_3%20M_i%5Ctimes%20%5Cwidehat%7BT%7D_i%20+%20u_i%2C)

To provide a reproducible example, first a simulation

```
n <- 100

set.seed(271)

Z <- runif(n)
e <- rnorm(n, sd = 0.5)
M <- as.integer(runif(n)) # dummy
u <- rnorm(n)

# Treat = 1 + 2*Z + e

alpha_0 <- 1
alpha_1 <- 2

Treat <- alpha_0 + alpha_1*Z + e 
  
# Y = 3 + M + 2*Treat + 3*Treat * M + e + u (ommited vars that determine Treat affect Y)

beta_0 <- 3
beta_1 <- 1
beta_2 <- 2
beta_3 <- 3

Y <- beta_0 + beta_1*M + beta_2*Treat + beta_3 * M*Treat + e + u
```

The first stage regression

```
fs <- lm(Treat ~ Z)

stargazer::stargazer(fs, type = "text")

===============================================
                        Dependent variable:    
                    ---------------------------
                               Treat           
-----------------------------------------------
Z                            2.383***          
                              (0.168)          
                                               
Constant                     0.835***          
                              (0.096)          
                                               
-----------------------------------------------
Observations                    100            
R2                             0.671           
Adjusted R2                    0.668           
Residual Std. Error       0.445 (df = 98)      
F Statistic           200.053*** (df = 1; 98)  
===============================================
```

And second stage

```
Treat_hat <- fitted(fs)

ss <- lm(Y ~ M + Treat_hat + M:Treat_hat)

stargazer::stargazer(ss, type = "text")

===============================================
                        Dependent variable:    
                    ---------------------------
                                 Y             
-----------------------------------------------
M                              1.230           
                              (1.717)          
                                               
Treat_hat                    2.243***          
                              (0.570)          
                                               
M:Treat_hat                  2.636***          
                              (0.808)          
                                               
Constant                      2.711**          
                              (1.213)          
                                               
-----------------------------------------------
Observations                    100            
R2                             0.727           
Adjusted R2                    0.718           
Residual Std. Error       2.539 (df = 96)      
F Statistic           85.112*** (df = 3; 96)   
===============================================
```

The problem now is that those Standard Errors aren't adjusted for the first stage, which looks like quite some work to do manually. As I'd do for any other IV regression, I'd prefer to just use `AER::ivreg`.

But I can't seem to get the same regression going there. Here are many possible iterations, that never quite do the same thing

```
AER::ivreg(Y ~ M + Treat + M:Treat | Z)
AER::ivreg(Y ~ M + Treat + M:Treat | M + Z)
Warning message:
In ivreg.fit(X, Y, Z, weights, offset, ...) :
  more regressors than instruments
```

These make sense, I guess

```
AER::ivreg(Y ~ M + Treat + M:Treat | M + Z + M:Z)
Call:
AER::ivreg(formula = Y ~ M + Treat + M:Treat | M + Z + M:Z)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            M        Treat      M:Treat  
      2.641        1.450        2.229        2.687
```

Surprisingly close, but not quite.

I couldn't find a way to tell `ivreg` that `Treat` and `M:Treat` aren't really two separate endogenous variables, but really just the same endogenous variable moved around and interacted with an exogenous one.

In conclusion,

i) Is there some way to mess with `ivreg` and make this work?

ii) Is there some other function for 2SLS that can just manually accept 1st and 2nd stage formulas without this sort of restriction, and that adjusts standard errors?

iii) What's the simplest way to get the correct SEs if there are no other alternatives? I didn't come across any direct R code, just a bunch of matrix multiplication formulas (although I didn't dig too deep for this one).

Thank you

Comment: In this particular case, since M is a dummy, I can also just run separate (Y ~ T | Z) IV regressions for the observations where M = 1 and for M = 0 to get equivalent results. I hope there's some neater way though.

Comment: I realized that the manual 2SLS SEs are just wrong because they use the second stage residuals (y - beta*X_hat) instead of the appropriate (y - beta*X) actual IV residuals. As a result, the formula they use for the variance multiplies by the wrong σ^2. So, to correct them, you should just calculate their SE, divide by the wrong σ and multiply by the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, if Z is a valid a valid instrument for Treat, M:Z should be a valid instrument for M:Treat, so, to me this makes sense:

```
AER::ivreg(Y ~ M + Treat + M:Treat | M + Z + M:Z)
```

I actually managed to back out the correct param values for a modified simulation:

```
n <- 100

set.seed(271)

Z <- runif(n)
e <- rnorm(n, sd = 0.5)
M <- round(runif(n)) # note: I changed from as.integer() to round() in order to get some 1's in the regression
u <- rnorm(n)

# Treat = 1 + 2*Z + e

alpha_0 <- 1
alpha_1 <- 2

Treat <- alpha_0 + alpha_1*Z + e 
beta_0 <- 3
beta_1 <- 1
beta_2 <- 2
beta_3 <- 3

Y <- beta_0 + beta_1*M + beta_2*Treat + beta_3 * M*Treat
```

Now:

```
    my_ivreg <- AER::ivreg(Y ~ M + Treat + M:Treat | M + Z + M:Z)

>summary(my_ivreg)
Call:
AER::ivreg(formula = Y ~ M + Treat + M:Treat | M + Z + M:Z)

Residuals:
       Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max
-1.332e-14 -7.105e-15 -3.553e-15 -8.882e-16  3.553e-15

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error   t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 3.000e+00  2.728e-15 1.100e+15   <2e-16 ***
M           1.000e+00  3.810e-15 2.625e+14   <2e-16 ***
Treat       2.000e+00  1.255e-15 1.593e+15   <2e-16 ***
M:Treat     3.000e+00  1.792e-15 1.674e+15   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 5.633e-15 on 96 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-Squared:     1,  Adjusted R-squared:     1
Wald test: 1.794e+31 on 3 and 96 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Which is what we were looking for...

Comment: Wait, there are no error terms in your Y, it's just deterministic! I now noticed that it was my mistake, I first forgot to add them and once I did I didn't change the code I'd pasted. I added them to your code and got the same results I had previously with your specification.

Comment: I tried cranking up the n, and this estimation does approach the actual values anyway, even though it's not equivalent to that particular 2SLS. At least this way we know the SEs are reliable though.

Comment: It's a great solution, and it should converge to the same results whenever Z is independent of M (so M:Z doesn't really change anything), which I guess is required anyway. It might give slightly higher variance since you're adding the extra kinda unnecessary instrument, but it's very close to perfect.

Comment: It is not very common to see specifications of `Treat:M ~ Z:M` variety in the literature (at least in economics). Most folks just do subsample analyses for M=0 and M=1.

Comment: Yeah, it turned out that it didn't really make sense for my application either as my advisor pointed out, so I gave up on it a couple of day ago to do as you said. Still though it was interesting though. Thanks for the answer and insight.